# About Coredata in use sqlite function

Tags: sqlite, function, core-data

SQL Statement :
SELECT julianday(strftime('%Y-%m-%d','2010-11-28 20:50:30'))  FROM TABLE

Coredata in how to use Sqlite function??

Comment: Core Data != SQLite-Wrapper. Certainly you connect to the SQLite-Database and do your thing but you should certainly use Core Data's APIs.

Comment: You're not looking up any data in that statement, you're just doing a date conversion. Why would you use SQLite for that?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a fetch request with the appropriate predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"julianDay = %@", aDate];
```